# Show variable type in XCode's "Quick Help"

Tags: c++, xcode, ide

Is there any way to have XCode display C++ variable types in Quick Help? Currently, when a variable is selected, it only shows "Declared int foo.cc".

In AppCode this works and is specially useful for "auto" variables, since it displays the deducted variable type.

It works correctly for methods.

Using XCode 7.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible in XCode 7.2 (or lower)

So far the closest I could find is to force XCode to show you an error. E.g. let's say you have this code:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
std::map<K, V> createMap()
{
    return std::map<K, V>();
}

void process()
{
    auto myMap = createMap<std::string, int>();
    // ...
}
```

and you need to find out what is type of myMap variable.

Create helper class and macro:

```
template <typename T> class DeductTypeCatcher {
public:
    DeductTypeCatcher() { T t = (void***)0; }
};

#define SHOW_DEDUCT_TYPE(t)     DeductTypeCatcher<decltype(t)> __catcher__;
```

Then add into your original code:

```
void process()
{
    auto myMap = createMap<std::string, int>();
    SHOW_DEDUCT_TYPE(myMap)
}
```

and XCode will immediately show you an **error**:

```
No viable conversion from 'void ***' to 'std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, int> > >'
```

or let's say you have this code:

```
void process()
{
    auto myMap = createMap<std::string, int>();
    for (auto it : myMap) { /*...*/ }
}
```

and want to find out the type of "it":

```
void process()
{
    auto myMap = createMap<std::string, int>();
    SHOW_DEDUCT_TYPE(*myMap.begin())
    for (auto it : myMap) { /*...*/ }
}
```

will show you an **error**:

```
Non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'void ***'
```

I know it is not a perfect solution, but at least better than nothing.

**EDITED:**

Another approach could be to rely on IDE itself.

E.g. in this example:

```
void process()
{
    auto myMap = createMap<std::string, int>();
    SHOW_DEDUCT_TYPE(*myMap.begin())
    for (auto it : myMap) {
    }
}
```

start typing "it" (without quotes) inside for loop. Autocomplete dialog will popup and you should see the type of "it" variable on the left side of autocomplete box. If type is too long then hover mouse over it and wait for a few seconds - the full type will be displayed (sometimes full type does not show up, then you have to press Ctrl+Space few times).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My intention with Quick Help was to quickly see the variable type. Yes I also found that the autocomplete dialog (Ctrl+Space) shows the type, but viewing it in the Quick Help would be faster.